# Open source php doc/x to pdf conversion?

Tags: php, pdf, docx, doc

Are there any open source PHP tools that i can use to convert .doc / .docx  to pdf ?

If you have any good tutorials or tools that would be greatly appreciated .

I was looking into phpLiveDocx but looks like they charge monthly.

Or maybe an .odt to pdf in php or linux ?

Comment: Are you sure about the monthly charge? I read it's part of the Zend Framework. Free, Open Source, etc if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yeah pretty positive its a service addon in zend.

Answer (score 0):

Try FPDF(dot)org. Dunno if it's open source but it seems easy to understand & use.

EDIT: Didn't notice that it didn't do conversions. Maybe this blog post will help: [Word to PDF conversion using OpenOffice on Windows](http://blog.rubypdf.com/2007/10/10/word-to-pdf-converter-in-php-using-openoffice-word2pdf/). Hopefully that works. If not, I have no idea.

Comment: This is for making pdf i need a converting :-/

Answer (score 0):

For a PHP-specific option check out [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) - this library is written in pure PHP and provides a set of classes to write to and read from different document file formats (including .doc and .docx)

Alternatively if you want an even easier life you could use a commercial API such as [Zamzar](https://developers.zamzar.com). This service has been around for 10+ years and provides an API for file conversion which you can call [directly from PHP](https://developers.zamzar.com/docs#section-Start_a_conversion_job).

Full disclosure: I'm the lead developer for the Zamzar API.

Comment: Thanks Chris, How does zamzar convert docx to pdf internally ? Do you use a paid library ?