# Symfony2 - How to convert doc or docx files to pdf

Tags: php, symfony, pdf-conversion

Is there any method in Symfony that converts MS word files (doc, docx) t pdf ?
Any integrated function, bundle? What are your experience with?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not in the framework itself, but it's the wrong question. In general, this question is "How to convert doc or docx files to PDF in PHP", since Symfony2/Cake/Zend/CodeIgniter is just PHP. There _could_ be a bundle for it, but what would a bundle do, other than wrap a general PHP-based library?

Comment: Thus, [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131526/open-source-php-doc-x-to-pdf-conversion) or [perhaps this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338254/how-can-i-convert-word-document-file-to-pdf-in-php) or [one of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=doc+to+pdf+php).

Comment: Thank you @halfer, could you plase answer this question ,so I can confirm the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some great PHP frameworks about at the moment (Symfony2 is on my list to try) but one of the things I notice here is that people often think that the framework should handle everything. However, these frameworks *are* just PHP, so in general if you have a need for extra functionality, just look for a PHP library that does what you want. There *might* be a Symfony2 bundle for this, but if not, make your own with the library you find `:-)`.

There are several questions here that list PHP approaches to converting Word documents (doc and docx) to PDF. For example, [try this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338254/how-can-i-convert-word-document-file-to-pdf-in-php).